# Radio Form Input's text not being styled

Tags: html, css

I can't get the form text to be styled. The text is left all the way at the top, while my radio inputs are correctly styled to be 100px from the top. Does it require a special attribute tag? I don't believe the documentation made note of that, if that's the case. Anyway, my code is:

```css
input[type='radio'] {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type='radio' name='level' value='choice1' checked='checked'>Choice 1</input>
  <input type='radio' name='level' value='choice2'>Choice 2</input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make labels out of the text as follows:

```css
.radio-label {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<form>
 <label class="radio-label">Choice 1 <input type='radio' name='level' value='choice1' checked='checked'></label>
 <label class="radio-label">Choice 2 <input type='radio' name='level' value='choice2'></label>
</form>
```

Comment: Just wanted to post the same answer!

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't have thought of that. It's an easy fix afterall, thank you.

Comment: @ArashHowaida Mark it as the correct answer, please

Comment: It said I need to wait a few minutes, I guess there is a minimum amount of time to be considered. I will of course :) It says 2 mins.

Comment: Oh, I just realized I have a few other `<label>` tags. Is there a way to style only this radio input label? label.radio didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info of the [W3 about the input type radio](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20101019/input.radio.html) you have a few mistakes:

1. This doesn't allow any content
2. The attribute `val` isn't allowed must be `value`
3. No need for the closing tag of the `input`

And with the [example of the wiki](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/radio), you need to restructure your code like this:

```css
label {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label><input type='radio' name='level' value='choice1' checked='checked'/>Choice 1</label>
  <label><input type='radio' name='level' value='choice2'/>Choice 2</label>
</form>
```

---

**Note:** Use the [validator of W3](https://validator.w3.org) to avoid structural mistakes

Comment: Good points, the val thing was just a typo. I will fix that. Thank you for the other tips, very helpful.

Comment: Glad to help @ArashHowaida just want to complement with backup links from the native source :)